# How can I run particular sets of JUnit tests under specific circumstances?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I have a Java codebase that is developed exclusively in Eclipse. There
are a set of JUnit4 tests that can be divided into two mutually exclusive
subsets based on when they are expected to run:

1. "Standard" tests should run when a developer right-clicks the test
   class (or containing project) and selects Run As > JUnit Test. Nothing
   unusual here—this is exactly how JUnit works in Eclipse.
2. "Runtime" tests should only run when called programmatically from
   within the application when it is started up in a specific state.

The two types of tests might sit adjacent to each other in the same Java
package. (Ideally we could intermix them in the same class, though
that's not a hard requirement.)

My first solution was to annotate the "Runtime" test classes with a new
`@TestOnLaunch` annotation. The application is able to find these classes,
and was running the tests contained in them (annotated with `@Test`) using
`JUnitCore.run(Class<?>...)`. However, these tests leak into the
"Standard" scenario above, because the Eclipse test runner will run any
method annotated with `@Test`, regardless of the intent of my custom class
annotation.

Next I tried moving the `@TestOnLaunch` annotation to the method level.
This prevents the "leakage" of the "Runtime" tests into the "Standard"
scenario, but now I can't seem to get `JUnitCore` to run those test
methods. `run.(Request)` with a `Request` targeted at the correct class and
method, for example, fails with "No runnable methods", presumably
because it can't find the `@Test` annotation (because it's not there).

I'm very interested to know if there's a "JUnit way" of solving this
kind of problem. Presumably I could write my own `Runner` (to run methods
annotated with `@TestOnLaunch`)—is this the right approach? If so, how do
I then kick off the testing programmatically with a bunch of classes,
analogous to calling `JUnitCore.run(Class<?>...)`?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mix the two type test method in the same test class, this below may help:

http://johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.jsp

You can use the filter feature to setup two test suite.

I setup three test suites in my project by defining several mark interfaces:

UnitTests, IntegrationTests, DeploySmokeTests, AcceptanceTests

And three test suites:

```
@RunWith(ClasspathSuite.class)
@SuiteTypes({UnitTests.class, IntegrationTests.class})
public class CommitTestSuite {}

@RunWith(ClasspathSuite.class)
@SuiteTypes({DeploySmokeTests.class})
public class DeploySmokeTestSuite {}

@RunWith(ClasspathSuite.class)
@SuiteTypes({AcceptanceTests.class})
public class AcceptanceTestSuite {}
```

Now you could achieve your goal by running specific test suite. An alternative solution is using junit category:

```
@Category(IntegrationTests.class)
public class SomeTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        ...
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        ....
    }
}

@RunWith(Categories.class)
@IncludeCategory(UnitTests.class, IntegrationTests.class)
@SuiteClasses( { //all test classes })
public class CommitTestSuite {}
```

As I said if you mix differenct type test method in one test class, the first one can't help you, but by using the seconde solution you could annotate your category interface on test method (I annotated it on test class in the example above). But if you choose the second solution, you have to maintain your test suite every time you add a new test class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The requirements I'm working with include avoiding the maintenance of any kind of external list that would need updating as new test classes were added.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should reevaluate why you're using JUnit tests at runtime; that seems like an odd choice for a problem that probably has a better solution.

However, you should look at using a `Filter` to determine which tests to run, possibly in conjunction with a custom annotation.

Comment: Using JUnit at runtime is a requirement that's been given to me. I can't change it at this stage. I will look at Filter.

Comment: I'm not sure Filter is going to help in this case. Presumably I implement shouldRun() and decide whether any Description given to the Filter should be run. The problem is going to be that, as far as I can see, all of the standard Runners insist on the 'Test' annotation. I wan't to _avoid_ that annotation on my "runtime" tests so that they don't get run by Eclipse using its internal runner. So unless I have a custom Runner here, I'm never going to get my 'TestOnLaunch' methods presented to shouldRun()—right?